# Attach More Files: Rerender Clears Selection

Tags: visualforce, attachment, rerender, commandbutton, apexinputfile

When am trying to click on Attach Another file button ,selected file on first input file is getting null.

Here is the code.

```
    public class SamplePageController{

 public  List<Attachment> allFileList {get; set;}
 public boolean showMorePanel {get;set;}

 public SamplePageController(){
  allFileList2 = new list<Attachment>();
 }

 public void addMoreFiles(){
     allFileList.add(new Attachment());
     showMorePanel = true;   
    }

}
```

---

```
 <apex:page controller="SamplePageController">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Attach Files" columns="1">
   <apex:outputPanel id="morefiles"> 
     <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showMorePanel}">
     <apex:repeat value="{!allFileList}" var="f">
       <apex:inputText label="File Name"/>
       <apex:inputfile value="{!f.body}" filename="{!f.name}">
       </apex:inputfile><br/>
     </apex:repeat> 
    </apex:outputPanel>  
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputPanel id="Mypanel">   
    <apex:outputPanel >   
    <apex:actionregion >    
    <apex:commandButton action="{!addMoreFiles}" value="Attach Another File" reRender="morefiles" style="float: left;" />
    </apex:actionregion><br/><br/> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>  
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>  
 </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

[image]

When I click on Attach Another file button,value of first input file is getting null.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an exact answer to your question but I think that, in consideration for heap size, you may want to change your code so the "Attach New File" button actually uploads the first attachment and then re-initializes the variable so a new file can be uploaded, instead of allowing X files to be uploaded at the same time.

That way you avoid the inevitable problems that will arise (after you fix the code) if the user tries to attach X number of files, and then the sheer size of those attachments blows your heap.

I've implemented this solution before, just as I described it, and it works wonders.

Comment: Also.  The OOB SFDC attachment UI doesn't permit multiple attachments to be uploaded in the same POST and were there a solution for the OP design, one would have thought SFDC would have provided it by now as the user benefit is obvious.